# Can't get path-dependent types to work in scala enumerations

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to spin my head around the path-dependent types in Scala's enums while making a Reads/Writes for Play2. Here is the code I have so far, it works, but with an asInstanceOf:

```
implicit def enumerationReads[T <: Enumeration](implicit t: T): Reads[t.Value] = {
    val validationError = ValidationError("error.expected.enum.name", t.values.mkString(", "))
    Reads.of[String].filter(validationError)(s ⇒ t.values.exists(v ⇒ v.toString == s)).map(t.withName(_))
  }

implicit def enumerationValueSetReads[T <: Enumeration](implicit t: T): Reads[t.ValueSet] =
    Reads.seq(enumerationReads[T]).map(seq ⇒ t.ValueSet(seq.asInstanceOf[Seq[t.Value]]: _*))
```

What can I do to get rid of the asInstanceOf on the last line? I tried typing the enumerationReads as enumerationReads[t.Value], but that doesn't work, the compiler complains in the argument of t.ValueSet that Seq[t.Value] cannot be cast to Seq[t.Value]. Yes, that didn't make sense to me too, until I started to realize these different t's might actually be different, since they are used in a closure.

So, what to do to make my code super-duper asInstanceOf free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code might do the trick:

```
implicit def enumerationReads(t : Enumeration) : Reads[t.Value] = {
    val validationError = ValidationError("error.expected.enum.name", t.values.mkString(", "))
    Reads.of[String].filter(validationError)(s ⇒ t.values.exists(v ⇒ v.toString == s)).map(t.withName(_))
}

implicit def enumerationValueSetReads(t: Enumeration): Reads[t.ValueSet] =
    Reads.seq(enumerationReads(t : t.type)).map(set => t.ValueSet(set : _*))
```

or maybe more useful

```
implicit def enumerationValueSetReads(t: Enumeration): Reads[Set[t.Value]] =
    Reads.set(enumerationReads(t : t.type))
```

An enumeration is already an object (of class `Enumeration`) so you can use it directly. You don't need to introduce a type `T`. To type your functions correctly the compiler has to check that types `Value` and `ValueSet` both belong to the correct instance of `Enumeration` (here `t`). That's called [path-dependent types](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html).

In the following code

```
class T extends Enumeration

object Animals extends T {
    val Cow, Pig, Rabbit = Value
}

object Food extends T {
    val Rice, Potatoes, Fries = Value
}
```

Both `Animals` and `Food` are instances of `T` but the types `T # Value`, `Animals.Value` and `Food.Value` are different. `T # Value` represent any type `Value` of any instance of `T` whereas `Animals.Value` (respectively `Food.Value`) is the type that belongs to `Animals` and `Animals` alone.

In the error "Seq[t.Value] cannot be cast to Seq[t.Value]", which i admit is very confusing, the two occurences of `t` are different instances. If you call `enumerationReads[T]` with type `T`, it considers its argument `t` to be any, unknown, instance of `T`. So you lose the track of the instance. That's why you have to call it with type `t.type`.

Comment: Thank you. The extra explanation was very helpful.

Comment: By the way, I'm starting to realize the IntelliJ errors are often false positives, thus pointing away from the right solution.